# Combobox(inside a DataGrid) Binding to Observable List not loading

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, datagrid

I have a `ComboBox` column inside a `DataGrid`. I need it to display values based on another WPF control, not in `DataGrid`. So, the values of `ComboBox` should change according to that control. I have created an `ObservableCollection` and binded it to the `ComboBox` but it does not display any values. For displaying dynamically, I have added `DropOpenOpened` event. But the `ComboBox` does not display any value. The list that populates the `ComboBox` is getting updated but its not displaying anything.

Below is the xaml code.
The `DataGrid` is bound to another `List`, whose values I fetch from DB.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="grid1" AutoGenerateColumns="False"   Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
     AlternatingRowBackground="Azure"  AlternationCount="2" CanUserReorderColumns="True" CanUserResizeRows="True" CanUserSortColumns="True"
              DataContext="attr">             
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding modify_user}" Header="Modified By" IsReadOnly="True"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding modify_date}" Header="Modified Date" IsReadOnly="True"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Source" Width="*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding source_value}"></TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox x:Name="combo_source" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=sourceComboDropdown}"                                         
                                    DisplayMemberPath="desc" SelectedValuePath="id" 
                                    SelectedItem="{Binding source_value}"  
                                    SelectedValue="{Binding Path=source_value,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"                           
                                    DropDownOpened="combo_source_DropDownOpened"/>                                      
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Target value" Width="*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding target_value}"></TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding targetComboDropdown}"                                      
                                    DisplayMemberPath="desc" SelectedValuePath="id" 
                                    SelectedItem="{Binding target_value}"  
                                  SelectedValue="{Binding Path=target_value,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                  DropDownOpened="ComboBox_DropDownOpened"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

The class of observablecollection is:

```
public static ObservableCollection<Source> sourceComboDropdown = 
   new ObservableCollection<Source>();
public static ObservableCollection<Source> targetComboDropdown =
   new ObservableCollection<Source>();

public class Source
{
   public string id { get; set; }
   public string desc { get; set; }
}
```

Where `desc` is the `DisplayMember` value and `id` is `SelectedValue`.

The class for `DataGrid` list is:

```
public static ObservableCollection<Attribute_Param> attr = 
   new ObservableCollection<Attribute_Param>();

public class Attribute_Param
{
   public string source_value { get; set; }
   public string target_value { get; set; }
   public string modify_user { get; set; }
   public DateTime modify_date { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried adding static resource. But since I need to dynamically update the values, I couldn't figure out a work around to use it.
I think I am missing something really small but cant figure out what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is unable to find the list sourceComboDropdown since the dataContext of the DataGrid  is attr which does not CONTAIN sourceCombo drop down.

I would set my datagrid datacontext to the whole viewmodel. i.e `DataGrid.DataContext=model` in the constructor of the code behind.

Then I can bind the datagrid to attr using : `ItemsSource="{Binding attr}"`  inside the DataGrid tag . Assuming attr is immediately in the VieWModel model.  That way it should be able to detect the combo box items soruce which is now in the data context i.e model contains sourceDropDown .

If that doesnt work , try this :

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn >
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate >
                                <ComboBox Loaded="LoadItemsSource"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>


  private void LoadItemsSource(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            ComboBox comboBox = sender as ComboBox;


            comboBox.ItemsSource=model.sourceDropDown;

        }
```

Comment: Hey Thanks! I tried the second solution and it works! I was struggling on this problem for a very long time.! If only there were unlimited upvotes !! ;)